# Does the measure exist?

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question. Let $\operatorname{card}(X)=\mathfrak{c} $. Does the measure exist? $\mu: \mathcal{P}(X) \longrightarrow \{0,1\}$

1. $\mu(X)=1$
2. $\forall{x\in X},\  \mu(\{x\})=0$

Could you give mi any hint?

Comment: Then for every $A,B\subset X$ with $A\cap B=\phi,$ either $\mu(A)=0$ or $\mu(B)=0.$

Answer (score 1):

No.

Take $X=\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose such measure exists.

Since $\displaystyle X=\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}[i,i+1]$ and points have measure $0$, then some $[n,n+1]$ has measure $1$.

Divide $[n,n+1]$ in half, and repeat the argument. You will arrive at a sequence of compact sets, measuring $1$, and which intersection will be a point. But since the measure of the first set is $< \infty$, then the measure of the intersection should be the limit of the measures. So $0=1$, contradiction.

Comment: Perhaps one should take note of the part of this argument in which countable additivity is used and finite additivity is not enough. ${}\qquad{}$